# SQL: Grouping Paired Rows Without Field to Aggregate On

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

So say I have the following:

| Timestamp | Event_Name |
| --- | --- |
| 10:47:00 | RESUME |
| 10:37:52 | SUSPEND |
| 10:26:20 | RESUME |
| 09:48:27 | SUSPEND |
| 09:39:13 | RESUME |
| 09:15:38 | SUSPEND |
| 09:11:42 | RESUME |

I want to be able to pair them as such:

| Suspend | Resume |
| --- | --- |
| null | 10:47:00 |
| 10:37:52 | 10:26:20 |
| 09:48:27 | 09:39:13 |
| 09:15:38 | 09:11:42 |

If each pair had another field to group on I would use a listagg window function but I can't. Lag function doesn't work either.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan, its Snowflake, live version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As having a DBMS containing window function, you can use the following query

```sql
WITH t AS
( 
  SELECT CASE
           WHEN Event_Name = 'SUSPEND' THEN
            Timestamp
         END AS Suspend,
         CASE
           WHEN Event_Name = 'RESUME' THEN
            Timestamp
         END AS Resume,
         SUM(CASE
               WHEN Event_Name = 'SUSPEND' THEN
                1
               ELSE
                0
             END) OVER(PARTITION BY Event_Name ORDER BY Timestamp) AS rn_suspend,
         SUM(CASE
               WHEN Event_Name = 'RESUME' THEN
                1
               ELSE
                0
             END) OVER(PARTITION BY Event_Name ORDER BY Timestamp) AS rn_resume  
    FROM t
)
SELECT s.suspend, r.resume
  FROM (SELECT * FROM t WHERE resume IS NOT NULL) AS r
  FULL JOIN (SELECT * FROM t WHERE suspend IS NOT NULL) AS s
    ON s.rn_suspend = r.rn_resume
 ORDER BY r.rn_resume DESC, s.rn_suspend DESC
```

where `SUM` window function is used to count the each switch for the `Event_Name`

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=574dcbde0122a84488627a9c07bcd1c2)</kbd>